# IP Changing Program

Tags: networking, ipv4

So, my work has several networks and small business locations all with an internet blocking server. The managers all rotate and want freedom from the server, AKA static IP addresses outside the range of DHCP.

my problem is that they all need access to each others network, so setting up an alternate configuration is not that useful. How would I create an application that will change my users IP Address so that it will match their static IP at the location they changed it too?

This is just their internal IP address on their local machine, and each location's network has a static ip waiting for them. Just have to change their IP Address.

Is there a batch file command that can help achieve this? if not maybe writing a script or going into a larger application?

Comment: what does java have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on the machine itself will be difficult. It needs to be able to recognise each network, and what will it do when connecting to an unknown network like a home network or a hotspot?

I think it would be better to let the DHCP server hand out static addresses from outside the normal dynamic address pool. That way everything keeps working automatically while also giving static addresses to the machines.

I know this is not a real answer to your question, but I hope this gives you an alternative.